# Error While Creating Data frame for Dictionary Variable

Tags: python-3.x

working with USDA for product Databse , the Database which in JSON format .However, i have cracked it using json package

USDA food Data json form Cracked into DataFrame:

[image: here]

But, few of the variables in the Data is on Dictionary Form

Am trying to create a DataFrame for variable ' Nutrients' .But getting the below Error

`Error while Creating the Database`:

[image]

Please help me in getting rid of error, below mentioned is the code
nutrients[]

```
for rec in db:
    fnuts = DataFrame(rec['nutrients'])
    fnuts['id'] = rec['id']
    nutrients.append(fnuts)`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


nutrients = pd.DataFrame(db1['nutrients'])
```